# How to set project properties of visual studio 2013 using cmake?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, cmake

In my vs2013 project file, I have "Program database file name" (from Project Properties->C/C++->Output Files) to `$(IntDir)vc$(PlatformToolsetVersion).pdb`.
I know how to do this manualy, but for cmake i don't know.

How can I set this property from cmake?

Answer (score 0):

You can use target properties [COMPILE_PDB_NAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/COMPILE_PDB_NAME.html) for the name and [COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/prop_tgt/COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) for the directory.

If you want to use the Visual Studio variables, you can try to use it directly in the variables above. If that's not working, a fallback is always to add the corresponding compiler options. In you case [`/Fd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wst99a9.aspx):

```
if (MSVC)
    add_compile_options("/Fd\"$(IntDir)vc$(PlatformToolsetVersion).pdb\"")
endif()
```

or with [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html):

```
add_compile_options("$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/Fd\"$(IntDir)vc$(PlatformToolsetVersion).pdb\">")
```